# OpenGL Matrices Strange Transformations

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, lwjgl

I have been trying to make a game engine, just to learn some new things, everything was working but I then decided that for lighting I would make my own matrices classes and pass the final matrix to the shader. Unfortunately this ended up breaking the whole rendering system as everything now stretches and is definitely not right. Currently I have messed around with the order of multiplication but it still doesn't work, I have had this problem for over a month and just want to fix it and continue making the engine.

Firstly, here is the default shader used on PC:

```
public static final String[] pcVertexShaderCode = new String[] {
    "attribute vec4 andor_vertexPosition;",
    "attribute vec3 andor_normal;",
    "attribute vec2 andor_vtextureCoord;",
    "attribute vec4 andor_vcolour;",
    "uniform mat4 andor_modelmatrix;",
    "uniform mat4 andor_viewmatrix;",
    "uniform mat4 andor_projectionmatrix;",
    "uniform mat4 andor_modelviewprojectionmatrix;",
    "varying vec4 andor_colour;",
    "varying vec2 andor_textureCoord;",
    "void andor_main();",
    "void main() {",
    "  andor_colour = andor_vcolour;",
    "  andor_textureCoord = andor_vtextureCoord;",
   // "  andor_modelviewprojectionmatrix = andor_modelmatrix * andor_viewmatrix * andor_projectionmatrix;",
    "  gl_Position = andor_modelviewprojectionmatrix * andor_vertexPosition;",
    "  andor_main();",
    "}" };

public static final String[] pcFragmentShaderCode = new String[] {
    "uniform sampler2D andor_texture;",
    "uniform float andor_hasTexture;",
    "varying vec4 andor_colour;",
    "varying vec2 andor_textureCoord;",
    "void andor_main();",
    "void main() {",
    "  if (andor_hasTexture > 0.5) {",
    "    gl_FragColor = andor_colour * texture2D(andor_texture, andor_textureCoord);",
    "  } else {",
    "    gl_FragColor = andor_colour;",
    "  }",
    "  andor_main();",
    "}" };
```

This is the render method which is called by each object in the scene:

```
    /* The method used to draw the object */
    public void render() {
        //Multiply the matrices together
        Matrix4D projectionViewMatrix = Matrix.multiply(Matrix.projectionMatrix, Matrix.viewMatrix);
        Matrix.modelViewProjectionMatrix = (Matrix.multiply(projectionViewMatrix, Matrix.modelMatrix));

        //Sky box in relatively the right place
//      Matrix4D modelViewMatrix = Matrix.multiply(Matrix.modelMatrix, Matrix.viewMatrix);
//      Matrix.modelViewProjectionMatrix = (Matrix.multiply(modelViewMatrix, Matrix.projectionMatrix));

//      Matrix4D modelProjectionMatrix = Matrix.multiply(Matrix.modelMatrix, Matrix.projectionMatrix);
//      Matrix.modelViewProjectionMatrix = (Matrix.multiply(Matrix.viewMatrix, modelProjectionMatrix));

//      Matrix4D modelViewMatrix = Matrix.multiply(Matrix.modelMatrix, Matrix.viewMatrix);
//      Matrix.modelViewProjectionMatrix = (modelViewMatrix);

//      //TEST
//      for (int a = 0; a < 16; a++) {
//          //2D WORKS!!!!! Kind of...
//          Matrix.modelViewProjectionMatrix.values[a] = Matrix.modelMatrix.values[a] * Matrix.projectionMatrix.values[a] * Matrix.viewMatrix.values[a];
//      }
        System.out.println(Matrix.modelViewProjectionMatrix.toString() + "\n");
        //Set the correct android shader
        Shader shader = defaultShader;
        if (currentShader != null)
            shader = currentShader;
        //Use the shader program
        GL20.glUseProgram(shader.program);
        //Enable the arrays as needed
        int vertexPositionAttribute = shader.getAttributeLocation("andor_vertexPosition");
        int normalAttribute = 0;
        int colourAttribute = 0;
        int texturesAttribute = 0;
        int modelMatrixAttribute = shader.getUniformLocation("andor_modelmatrix");
        int viewMatrixAttribute = shader.getUniformLocation("andor_viewmatrix");
        int projectionMatrixAttribute = shader.getUniformLocation("andor_projectionmatrix");
        int matrixAttribute = shader.getUniformLocation("andor_modelviewprojectionmatrix");
        GL20.glUniformMatrix4(modelMatrixAttribute, false, BufferUtils.createFlippedBuffer(Matrix.modelMatrix.getValues()));
        GL20.glUniformMatrix4(viewMatrixAttribute, false, BufferUtils.createFlippedBuffer(Matrix.viewMatrix.getValues()));
        GL20.glUniformMatrix4(projectionMatrixAttribute, false, BufferUtils.createFlippedBuffer(Matrix.projectionMatrix.getValues()));
        GL20.glUniformMatrix4(matrixAttribute, false, BufferUtils.createFlippedBuffer(Matrix.modelViewProjectionMatrix.getValues()));
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionAttribute);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.verticesHandle);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexPositionAttribute, this.vertexValuesCount, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        if (this.normalsData != null) {
            normalAttribute = shader.getAttributeLocation("andor_normal");
            GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalAttribute);
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.normalsHandle);
            GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalAttribute, this.vertexValuesCount, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        }
        if (this.colourData != null) {
            colourAttribute = shader.getAttributeLocation("andor_vcolour");
            GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(colourAttribute);
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.coloursHandle);
            GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(colourAttribute, this.colourValuesCount, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        }
        if (this.textureData != null) {
            texturesAttribute = shader.getAttributeLocation("andor_vtextureCoord");
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texturesHandle);
            GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(texturesAttribute);
            GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(texturesAttribute, this.textureValuesCount, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            GL20.glUniform1i(shader.getUniformLocation("andor_texture"), 0);
            if (texture != null)
                GL20.glUniform1f(shader.getUniformLocation("andor_hasTexture"), 1f);
        }
        if (this.drawOrder != null) {
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.drawOrderHandle);
            GL11.glDrawElements(this.renderMode, this.drawOrder.length, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        } else {
            //Draw the arrays
            GL11.glDrawArrays(this.renderMode, 0, this.verticesData.length / this.vertexValuesCount);
        }
        //Disable the arrays as needed
        if (this.normalsData != null)
            GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalAttribute);
        if (this.textureData != null)
            GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(texturesAttribute);
        if (this.colourData != null)
            GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(colourAttribute);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexPositionAttribute);
        //Stop using the shader program
        GL20.glUseProgram(0);
    }
```

Then here are the methods used to apply the translations to an object in the scene before rendering:

```
/* The method used to update the current view matrix */
public void updateViewMatrix() {
    //Get the position
    Vector3D p = this.getPosition();
    //Get the rotation
    Vector3D r = this.getRotation();
    //Get the scale
    Vector3D s = this.getScale();
    //Save the current matrix
    clone = Arrays.copyOf(Matrix.modelMatrix.getValues(), 16);
    //Scale by the specified amount
    Matrix.modelMatrix = Matrix.scale(Matrix.modelMatrix, s);
    //Rotate by the specified amount
    Matrix.modelMatrix = Matrix.rotate(Matrix.modelMatrix, r.x, 1, 0, 0);
    Matrix.modelMatrix = Matrix.rotate(Matrix.modelMatrix, r.y, 0, 1, 0);
    Matrix.modelMatrix = Matrix.rotate(Matrix.modelMatrix, r.z, 0, 0, 1);
    //Move to the correct position
    Matrix.modelMatrix = Matrix.translate(Matrix.modelMatrix, p);
}

/* The method used to restore the current view matrix */
public void restoreViewMatrix() {
    //Restore the current matrix
    Matrix.modelMatrix.values = clone;
}
```

In a camera class this is used to move the players view:

```
    //Get the rotation
    Vector3D r = this.getRotation();
    //Get the position
    Vector3D p = this.getPosition();
    //Get the scale
    Vector3D s = this.getScale();
    //Rotate by the specified amount
    Matrix.viewMatrix = Matrix.rotate(Matrix.viewMatrix, r.x, 1, 0, 0);
    Matrix.viewMatrix = Matrix.rotate(Matrix.viewMatrix, r.y, 0, 1, 0);
    Matrix.viewMatrix = Matrix.rotate(Matrix.viewMatrix, r.z, 0, 0, 1);

    //Move to the correct position
    Matrix.viewMatrix = Matrix.translate(Matrix.viewMatrix, p);

    //Scale by the correct amount
    Matrix.viewMatrix = Matrix.scale(Matrix.viewMatrix, s);
```

Here is the Matrix4D class:

```
public class Matrix4D {

    /* The values within this matrix */
    public float[] values;

    /* The default constructor */
    public Matrix4D() {
        //Create the values
        this.values = new float[16];
    }

    /* The constructor with the values given */
    public Matrix4D(float[] values) {
        //Create the values
        this.values = values;
    }

    /* The constructor with the values given */
    public Matrix4D(float[][] values) {
        //Load the values
        load(values);
    }

    /* The method used to set the values given a 2 dimensional array */
    public void load(float[][] values) {
        this.values = new float[] {
                values[0][0], values[0][1], values[0][2], values[0][3],
                values[1][0], values[1][1], values[1][2], values[1][3],
                values[2][0], values[2][1], values[2][2], values[2][3],
                values[3][0], values[3][1], values[3][2], values[3][3]
        };
    }

    /* The method used to get a value using the coordinate within this matrix */
    public float get(int x, int y) {
        //Get the position
        int position = x + (y * 4);
        //Return the value
        return this.values[position];
    }

    /* The method used to return a string representation of this matrix */
    public String toString() {
        //Return the string
        return "[ " + this.values[0] + " " + this.values[1] + " " + + this.values[2] + " " + + this.values[3] + " ]" + "\n" +
               "[ " + this.values[4] + " " + this.values[5] + " " + + this.values[6] + " " + + this.values[7] + " ]" + "\n" +
               "[ " + this.values[8] + " " + this.values[9] + " " + + this.values[10] + " " + + this.values[11] + " ]" + "\n" +
               "[ " + this.values[12] + " " + this.values[13] + " " + + this.values[14] + " " + + this.values[15] + " ]";
    }

    /* The method used to get the values */
    public float[] getValues() { return this.values; }

    /* The method used to get the values in a 2D array */
    public float[][] getValues2DArray() {
        //The array
        float[][] array = new float[4][4];
        //Go through each value
        int column = 0;
        int row = 0;
        while (column * row < array.length) {
            row ++;
            if (row >= 4) {
                column++;
                row = 0;
            }
            array[column][row] = this.values[column * row];
        }
        //Return the array
        return array;
    }

}
```

Here is the Matrix class:

```
package org.andor.core;

public class Matrix {

    /* The different matrices */
    public static Matrix4D modelMatrix = new Matrix4D();
    public static Matrix4D viewMatrix = new Matrix4D();
    public static Matrix4D projectionMatrix = new Matrix4D();
    public static Matrix4D modelViewProjectionMatrix = new Matrix4D();

    /* The static method used to load an identity matrix */
    public static void loadIdentity(Matrix4D matrix) {
        //Load the identity matrix
        matrix.load(new float[][] {
                new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        });
    }

    /* The static method used to add two matrices together */
    public static Matrix4D add(Matrix4D matrixA, Matrix4D matrixB) {
        //Create a new matrix
        Matrix4D matrix = new Matrix4D();
        //Go through each value
        for (int a = 0; a < matrix.values.length; a++)
            //Assign the current value
            matrix.values[a] = matrixA.values[a] + matrixB.values[a];
        //Return the matrix
        return matrix;
    }

    /* The static method used to subtract a matrix (B) from another (A) */
    public static Matrix4D subtract(Matrix4D matrixA, Matrix4D matrixB) {
        //Create a new matrix
        Matrix4D matrix = new Matrix4D();
        //Go through each value
        for (int a = 0; a < matrix.values.length; a++)
            //Assign the current value
            matrix.values[a] = matrixB.values[a] - matrixA.values[a];
        //Return the matrix
        return matrix;
    }

    /* The static method used to multiply two matrices together */
    public static Matrix4D multiply(Matrix4D matrixA, Matrix4D matrixB) {
        //Create a new matrix
        Matrix4D matrix = new Matrix4D(new float[][] {
                new float[] {
                        (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[12]),
                        (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[13]),
                        (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[14]),
                        (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[15])
                },
                new float[] {
                        (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[12]),
                        (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[13]),
                        (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[14]),
                        (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[15])
                },
                new float[] {
                        (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[12]),
                        (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[13]),
                        (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[14]),
                        (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[15])
                },
                new float[] {
                        (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[12]),
                        (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[13]),
                        (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[14]),
                        (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[15])
                }
        });
        //Return the matrix
        return matrix;
    }

    /* The static method used to transpose a matrix */
    public static Matrix4D transpose(Matrix4D matrix) {
        //Get the values from the matrix
        float[][] values = matrix.getValues2DArray();
        //The new values
        float[][] newValues = new float[4][4];
        //Go through the array
        for (int y = 0; y < values.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < values[y].length; x++) {
                //Assign the new value
                newValues[x][y] = values[y][x];
            }
        }
        //Return the matrix
        return new Matrix4D(newValues);
    }

    /* The static method used to translate a matrix */
    public static Matrix4D translate(Matrix4D matrix, Vector3D vector) {
        //The transform matrix
        Matrix4D transform = new Matrix4D(new float[][] {
                new float[] { 1, 0, 0, vector.x },
                new float[] { 0, 1, 0, vector.y },
                new float[] { 0, 0, 1, vector.z },
                new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        });
        //Add onto the matrix and return the result
        return multiply(matrix, transform);
    }

    /* The static method used to rotate a matrix */
    public static Matrix4D rotate(Matrix4D matrix, float angle, int x, int y, int z) {
        //The transform matrix
        Matrix4D transform = new Matrix4D();
        //Calculate the values needed
        float cos = (float) Math.cos(angle);
        float sin = (float) Math.sin(angle);
        //Check the x y and z values
        if (x == 1) {
            transform.load(new float[][] {
                    new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 },
                    new float[] { 0, cos, -sin, 0 },
                    new float[] { 0, sin, cos, 0 },
                    new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
            });
        } else if (y == 1) {
            transform.load(new float[][] {
                    new float[] { cos, 0, sin, 0 },
                    new float[] { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
                    new float[] { -sin, 0, cos, 0 },
                    new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
            });
        } else if (z == 1) {
            transform.load(new float[][] {
                    new float[] { cos, -sin, 0, 0 },
                    new float[] { sin, cos, 0, 0 },
                    new float[] { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                    new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
            });
        }
        //Add onto the matrix and return the result
        return multiply(matrix, transform);
    }

    /* The static method used to scale a matrix */
    public static Matrix4D scale(Matrix4D matrix, Vector3D vector) {
        //The transform matrix
        Matrix4D transform = new Matrix4D(new float[][] {
                new float[] { vector.x, 0, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, vector.y, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, 0, vector.z, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        });
        //Add onto the matrix and return the result
        return multiply(matrix, transform);
    }

    /* The static method used to return an orthographic projection matrix */
    public static Matrix4D ortho(float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float zfar, float znear) {
//      Matrix4D mat = new Matrix4D();
//      mat.values[0] = 2 / (right - left);
//      mat.values[5] = 2 / (top - bottom);
//      mat.values[10] = - 2 / (zfar - znear);
//      mat.values[12] = - (right + left) / (right - left);
//      mat.values[13] = -(top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
//      mat.values[14] = -(zfar + znear) / (zfar - znear);
//      return mat;
        return new Matrix4D(new float[][] {
                new float[] { 2 / (right - left), 0, 0, -((right + left) / (right - left)) },
                new float[] { 0, 2 / (top - bottom), 0, -((top + bottom) / (top - bottom)) },
                new float[] { 0, 0, -2 / (zfar - znear), -((zfar + znear) / (zfar - znear)) },
                new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        });
    }

    /* The static method used to return a perspective projection matrix */
    public static Matrix4D perspective(float fov, float aspect, float zNear, float zFar) {
        //Calculate the values that need to be calculated the most frequently
        float f = 1.0f / (float) Math.tan(fov / 2 * (Math.PI / 360.0));
        float rangeReciprocal = 1.0f / (zNear - zFar);

        Matrix4D matrix = new Matrix4D();

        //Set the matrix values
        matrix.values[0] = f / aspect;
        matrix.values[1] = 0.0f;
        matrix.values[2] = 0.0f;
        matrix.values[3] = 0.0f;

        matrix.values[4] = 0.0f;
        matrix.values[5] = f;
        matrix.values[6] = 0.0f;
        matrix.values[7] = 0.0f;

        matrix.values[8] = 0.0f;
        matrix.values[9] = 0.0f;
        matrix.values[10] = (zFar + zNear) * rangeReciprocal;
        matrix.values[11] = -1.0f;

        matrix.values[12] = 0.0f;
        matrix.values[13] = 0.0f;
        matrix.values[14] = 2.0f * zFar * zNear * rangeReciprocal;
        matrix.values[15] = 0.0f;
        return matrix;
    }
}
```

This is what the current output looks like:

[image]

EDIT: I have since tried changing the multiplication just before giving the matrix to the shader to not use matrix multiplication as an experiment. This results in making 2D appear to wok properly however rotation seems to make the object get smaller, it then flips and then it will get bigger again but at this point it is inverted.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have no idea what the problem is. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two things that made this effect happen.

1. The matrix needed to be transposed before using the matrix in the shader
2. The perspective matrix wont work unless the znear value is 1 or over

Comment: `znear >=1` is not a requirement for perspective matrices. Usually, it must be positive, though.

Comment: It's strange how it happened, I suppose during the matrix multiplication one of the values decreased rather than decreased as it was multiplied by a value less than 1.

Comment: Setting nearVal to 1 fixed a perspective warping issue for me, thanks.